# Product Pages - "Error processing request" Error Logs=

Tags: magento-1.9

When trying to access product pages, I'm getting an error processing request. I've checked the var/report log and it showed the following. Any ideas what might be going on?
[image]

Comment: version 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***canShowBlock()*** is not function of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` as per as default magento.It is function of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` & `Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Layer`.

So,you need to remove *`$this->canShowBlock()` fr*om `app/design/frontend/nationwide/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Comment: Thank you for the reply Amit. I'm simply to blame as I mistakenly saved the wrong file over the view.html. Reverted to old and back in business.